# Fetch latest posts from social media via dialogflow

Tags: web-scraping, dialogflow-es, chatbot

Is it possible to fetch latest posts from Facebook and Twitter and youtube via dilaogflow when somebody asks "what's new?"

Comment: Do you mean scrapping from public pages?

Comment: @sai.raj yes exactly

Comment: you can use [request](https://github.com/request/request) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) in nodejs for web scraping and display the scraped content to the user in response

Comment: @sai.raj what about selenium with nodejs?

Comment: I think selenium would take more time to respond.

Comment: You can try casperjs

Comment: @sai.raj thank you :-)

Comment: Found a GitHub [link](https://github.com/dansalerno712/Node-Twitter-Scraper) You can give it a go !

Comment: @sai.raj thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible in theory.
You can do it by make an intent which will be triggered with phrases like "what's new", and then you will have to enable webhook for that intent where you will write your code to fetch latest posts from Facebook etc.

But it won't be practical because in DialogFlow there is a time limit of 5 seconds within which your webhook should respond to the user otherwise there will be time-out exception. And I don't think 5 seconds are enough to fetch the latest posts.

Comment: 5 second is a lot of time, we can get response from tens of API if it is broken correctly and properly, mostly apis have 200ms response time in average, 5sec have 5000ms, we can call 25 apis in 5 sec (5000/200=25)